# micro_ros and control

Tags: ros2, ros2-control, micro-ros

I am working with ROS2 but im new to a uROS. Currently I am doubting about a control of cleaning robot. There is a uC and high-level PC inside. I have a few questions:

1. Which logic should be on the uC side and on the pc side. For example, data from promixity sensors should be processed (for example to stop the wheels when there is a obstacle) on the uC or it should be send to the high level PC?
2. Is it reasonable to use ros2_control if I build the program on uC with Micro Ros? Since it's a differential robot then ros2_controls seems worth using for that. Does using ros2_control (hardware interface) excludes using micro ros?

I would be thanksful for help!

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't have any experience with micro-ros. As far as I know there is no port of ros2_control itself to micro-ros.

You could use a [topic-based hardware component](https://github.com/PickNikRobotics/topic_based_ros2_control) sending topics from ros2_control towards micro-ros on your uC. But maybe you want to consider writing a custom hardware component, which exports the interfaces (commands and states, like your proximity sensor) and connects to your uC via a simple serial protocol.

On top of that you can implement whichever behavior, navigation stack etc. On the uC I'd only write simple checks (outlier detection of sensor etc), and maybe safety critical parts like emergency stop etc.